# Uploading DB to server from local is not matching the post dates

Tags: custom-post-types, date

I just created a custom WP CMS and am having trouble with the custom post maintaining the correct order on the front-end.  In the back end the date order is correct but is not being reflected on the front-end in the same order.  When I download the DB to my local machine, the order is right but once on the server, it shows up differently?

Comment: Check for differences in your local environment vs your remote environment?

Comment: I've seen this before. It was something funky with server timezone settings and/or the timezone set on the server or within PHP. (It was in just some custom CMS I wrote and on DB upload all the times were wrong, didn't bother to fix it as all times were just out by a few hours but all the times were out by the same amount)

Answer (score 1):

WordPress uses the [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) function to set the server timezone. This is based on the timezone offset setting under Settings->General.

Check your setting to make sure it matches your timezone at: http://yourdomain.com/wp-admin/options-general.php

If changing your timezone via the setting doesn't work, there's probably nothing you can do to change this without touching your server configuration. You need to speak to your host and have them set your server timezone to the correct offset.

If you have access to your php.ini file, search for the following setting and set your [timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php):

```
date.timezone = “”
```

Hope this helps you out.